# Get billing address line 1 and line 2 in order collection: Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, order-collection

I am trying to get billing address line 1 and line 2 with city and state in order collection.

Here is my code:

```
$oid = 1;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($oid);
$order->getBillingAddress();
```

But it is not giving any value of billing address.

When I print **$order** variable it shows **billing_address_id** index with the integer value.

See below:

```
[0] => Array            
    (           
        [entity_id] => 1            
        [state] => processing           
        [status] => processing          
        [coupon_code] =>            
        [protect_code] =>           
        [shipping_description] => My carrier            
        [is_virtual] => 0           
        [store_id] => 1         
        [customer_id] =>            
        [base_discount_amount] => 0.0000            
        [base_discount_canceled] =>             
        [base_discount_invoiced] => 0.0000          
        [base_discount_refunded] =>             
        [base_grand_total] => 625.9800          
        [base_shipping_amount] => 7.9800            
        [base_shipping_canceled] =>             
        [base_shipping_invoiced] => 7.9800          
        [base_shipping_refunded] =>             
        [base_shipping_tax_amount] =>           
        [base_shipping_tax_refunded] =>             
        [base_subtotal] => 516.7200         
        [base_subtotal_canceled] =>             
        [base_subtotal_invoiced] =>             
        [base_subtotal_refunded] =>             
        [base_tax_amount] => 101.2776           
        [base_tax_canceled] =>          
        [base_tax_invoiced] => 101.2776         
        [base_tax_refunded] =>          
        [base_to_global_rate] => 1.0000         
        [base_to_order_rate] => 1.0000          
        [base_total_canceled] =>            
        [base_total_invoiced] => 625.9776           
        [base_total_invoiced_cost] => 625.9776          
        [base_total_offline_refunded] =>            
        [base_total_online_refunded] =>             
        [base_total_paid] => 625.9800           
        [base_total_qty_ordered] =>             
        [base_total_refunded] =>            
        [discount_amount] => 0.0000         
        [discount_canceled] =>          
        [discount_invoiced] => 0.0000           
        [discount_refunded] =>          
        [grand_total] => 625.9800           
        [shipping_amount] => 7.9800         
        [shipping_canceled] =>          
        [shipping_invoiced] => 7.9800           
        [shipping_refunded] =>          
        [shipping_tax_amount] => 0.0000         
        [shipping_tax_refunded] =>          
        [store_to_base_rate] => 1.0000          
        [store_to_order_rate] => 1.0000         
        [subtotal] => 516.7200          
        [subtotal_canceled] =>          
        [subtotal_invoiced] =>          
        [subtotal_refunded] =>          
        [tax_amount] => 101.2776            
        [tax_canceled] =>           
        [tax_invoiced] => 101.2776          
        [tax_refunded] =>           
        [total_canceled] =>             
        [total_invoiced] => 625.9776            
        [total_offline_refunded] =>             
        [total_online_refunded] =>          
        [total_paid] => 625.9800            
        [total_qty_ordered] => 2.0000           
        [total_refunded] =>             
        [can_ship_partially] =>             
        [can_ship_partially_item] =>            
        [customer_is_guest] => 0            
        [customer_note_notify] =>           
        [billing_address_id] => 101         
        [customer_group_id] => 0            
        [edit_increment] =>             
        [email_sent] =>             
        [send_email] =>             
        [forced_shipment_with_invoice] =>           
        [payment_auth_expiration] =>            
        [quote_address_id] =>           
        [quote_id] =>           
        [shipping_address_id] => 102            
        [adjustment_negative] =>            
        [adjustment_positive] =>            
        [base_adjustment_negative] =>           
        [base_adjustment_positive] =>           
        [base_shipping_discount_amount] => 0.0000           
        [base_subtotal_incl_tax] => 617.9976            
        [base_total_due] => 625.9800            
        [payment_authorization_amount] =>           
        [shipping_discount_amount] => 0.0000            
        [subtotal_incl_tax] => 617.9976         
        [total_due] => 625.9800         
        [weight] => 0.0000          
        [customer_dob] =>           
        [increment_id] => 100000115         
        [applied_rule_ids] =>           
        [base_currency_code] => USD         
        [customer_email] => guest_5ad06dd73f2e8@mail.com            
        [customer_firstname] => John            
        [customer_lastname] => DOE          
        [customer_middlename] =>            
        [customer_prefix] =>            
        [customer_suffix] =>            
        [customer_taxvat] =>            
        [discount_description] =>           
        [ext_customer_id] =>            
        [ext_order_id] =>           
        [global_currency_code] => USD           
        [hold_before_state] =>          
        [hold_before_status] =>             
        [order_currency_code] => USD            
        [original_increment_id] =>          
        [relation_child_id] =>          
        [relation_child_real_id] =>             
        [relation_parent_id] =>             
        [relation_parent_real_id] =>            
        [remote_ip] =>          
        [shipping_method] => flatrate_flatrate          
        [store_currency_code] => USD            
        [store_name] =>             
        [x_forwarded_for] =>            
        [customer_note] =>          
        [created_at] => 2012-08-31 01:48:27         
        [updated_at] => 2016-11-11 18:08:44         
        [total_item_count] => 2         
        [customer_gender] =>            
        [discount_tax_compensation_amount] =>           
        [base_discount_tax_compensation_amount] =>          
        [shipping_discount_tax_compensation_amount] =>          
        [base_shipping_discount_tax_compensation_amnt] =>           
        [discount_tax_compensation_invoiced] =>             
        [base_discount_tax_compensation_invoiced] =>            
        [discount_tax_compensation_refunded] =>             
        [base_discount_tax_compensation_refunded] =>            
        [shipping_incl_tax] => 7.9800           
        [base_shipping_incl_tax] => 7.9800          
        [coupon_rule_name] =>           
        [gift_message_id] =>            
        [paypal_ipn_customer_notified] => 0         
    )
```

How can I retrieve billing address line 1, line 2, city and state in order collection in Magento 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Following code will easily get Customer street address line 1, 2 and state**

```
  $orderId = 1222;
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
  $order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository')->get($orderId);

  /*get street line 1 and line 2 values */

  $billingaddress=$order->getBillingAddress();   
  $billingstreet=$order->getBillingAddress()->getStreet();
  $billingstreet1=$billingstreet[0];
  $billingstreet2=$billingstreet[1];

  /*  get state value */

  $billingstate=$order->getBillingAddress()->getRegion();
```

Comment: You have never used first line variable. why you wrote this?

Comment: store street first line in $billingstreet1 variable and street second line in $billingstreet2 variable. please check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting street and other info from billing like this:

```
$oid = 1;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($oid);


$city =  $order->getBillingAddress()->getCity();
$street= $order->getBillingAddress()->getStreet();
$region= $order->getBillingAddress()->getRegion();
```

Comment: I cannot get "getBillingAddress" in my array index. How can I fetch like yours. See my updated question.

Comment: How can I get billing address line 1 and billing address line 2?

Answer (score 0):

> $oid = 1; $objectManager =
>   \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); $order =
>   $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($oid);
>
> $city =  $order->getBillingAddress()->getCity(); $street=
>   $order->getBillingAddress()->getStreetLine(1); $street=
>   $order->getBillingAddress()->getStreetLine(2); $street=
>   $order->getBillingAddress()->getStreetLine(3); $region=
>   $order->getBillingAddress()->getRegion();

Try These it will work.